# Uncaught ReferenceError: text is not defined in my javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to submit to a database, using php and jquery (see code snippet below).

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#butsave').on('click', function() {
        $("#butsave").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        var idno = $('#idno').val();
        if(idno!=""){
            $.ajax({
                url: "common/register-details.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: idno              
                },
                cache: false,
             success: function(dataResult){
                    var obj = JSON.parse(text);
                    var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
                    if(dataResult.statusCode==200){
                        $("#butsave").removeAttr("disabled");
                        $('#register-id').find('input:text').val('');
                        $("#success").show();
                        $('#success').html('Data added successfully !');                        
                    }
                    else if(dataResult.statusCode==201){
                       alert("Error occured !");
                    }

                }
            });
        }
        else{
            alert('Please fill all the field !');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

However i get the following error

```
ReferenceError: text is not defined
```

When I use php with no jquery it works. Could anybody please tell me what the error could be?

Answer (score 1):

you are doing `var obj = JSON.parse(text);`, there is no `text`.

Comment: how should i parse datafrom the form to JSON?

Comment: what data? the response? You are already doing that on the next line, `var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);`

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line

```
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
```

as there is no text variable declared.

This will solve your issue.

Still your program not work then put your HTML code clock, php code block and javascript/jquery code block in question.